# Jlabels flickering or randomly not showing

Tags: java, synchronization, overriding, paint, repaint

I have a problem with a Java 2d game I'm developing.

Some of the game screen elements are drawn in a  `Jpanel` overriding the  `paint()` method and some other elements are `Jlabels` added to that panel.

The problem is that the elements drawn in the `paint()` method are always up to date (I recall a `Jpanel.repaint()` every 30ms from a thread) but the `Jlabels` often are not shown or are blinking in a random way.

I've searched a lot but couldn't find a way to update all the elements at the same time.

This is the core structure of the code:

**Main Class**

```
final class ATC_sim {
 
    // ...

    public CustomLabel[] label; 
    // CustomLabel is just a class in which are organized differents JLabels in
    // a certain relative position.  

    // ...
    
    private ATC_sim(){
        initGui();
        initGame();
    }

    private void initGui(){
        frame = new JFrame();
        pGame = new GamePanel(this);
        for(int i=0; i< label.length; i++){
            pGame.add(label[i]);
        }
        frame.add(pGame);
        // ...
    }

    private void initGame(){
        loop = new Loop(this, 30);                  
        thread = new Thread(loop);
        thread.start();
        
        pGame.repaint();
    }

    // method recalled every 30ms from thread(loop)
    public void updateGame(){         
        // do the math of the game (in which I also move the position of labels)
        // ...
        for(int i=0; i< label.length; i++){
            label[i].update(); // this method update text in Jlabels and position of label.
        }


        pGame.repaint();
    }
}
```

**GamePanel class**

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
    // ...

    public GamePanel(ATC_sim a) {
        this.atc = a;
        // ...
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        
        // do some drawings according to some variable calculated in updateGame()


    }
}
```

Comment: You should be overriding `paintComponent` but we need to see your code

Comment: Did you read [Swing’s Threading Policy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading)? Don’t modify the UI from a background thread. Use `javax.swing.Timer` to perform a UI action repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

At first, if you want better performance and a lower chance of lagging/stuttering, use `paintImmediately()` instead of `repaint()`.

It could be, that this solves your problem already.

The second part is: Do you use double buffering? If you use this, this problem will definitely disappear (in my oppinion).